# Can we create duplicate Objects in array based on a key which is an array itself?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

For example:-
Based on the **date** key which is an array can we split the same object into multiple objects depending on the date array and each new object created with a unique **date** value.

This is the initial array that we need to transform:---

```
[
    {
        artistId: [2, 5]
        artistName: "Chloe Feoranzo, Eric"
        city: "Bangalore, India"
        cityId: 1
        date: ["October 2020", "September 2020"]
        genre: "Nu Jazz"
    },
    {
        artistId: [2, 5]
        artistName: "Eric"
        city: "Bangalore, India"
        cityId: 1
        date: ["August 2020", "January 2020"]
        genre: "Nu Jazz"
    }
]
```

And this is the transformed array after splitting the objects based on the date key of an object:---

```
[
    {
        artistId: [2, 5]
        artistName: "Chloe Feoranzo, Eric"
        city: "Bangalore, India"
        cityId: 1
        date: "October 2020"
        genre: "Nu Jazz"
    },
    {
        artistId: [2, 5]
        artistName: "Chloe Feoranzo, Eric"
        city: "Bangalore, India"
        cityId: 1
        date: "September 2020"
        genre: "Nu Jazz"
    },
    {
        artistId: [2, 5]
        artistName: "Eric"
        city: "Bangalore, India"
        cityId: 1
        date: "August 2020"
        genre: "Nu Jazz"
    },
    {
        artistId: [2, 5]
        artistName: "Eric"
        city: "Bangalore, India"
        cityId: 1
        date: "January 2020"
        genre: "Nu Jazz"
    },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried ? You can use `Array.reduce` and add as many entries as required while transforming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
    {
        artistId: [2, 5],
        artistName: "Chloe Feoranzo, Eric",
        city: "Bangalore, India",
        cityId: 1,
        date: ["October 2020", "September 2020"],
        genre: "Nu Jazz",
    },
    {
        artistId: [2, 5],
        artistName: "Eric",
        city: "Bangalore, India",
        cityId: 1,
        date: ["August 2020", "January 2020"],
        genre: "Nu Jazz",
    }
]


const result = arr.reduce(
  (acc, item) => acc.concat(
    item.date.map((date) => Object.assign({}, item, { date: date }))
  ),
  []
);

console.log(result);
```

If you've got things like spread operators available, you could probably do something like:

```
const result = arr.reduce(
  (acc, item) => acc.concat(
    item.date.map((date) => ({ ...item, date }))
  ),
  []
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simplest method you could do:

```js
const arr = [{
    artistId: [2, 5],
    artistName: "Chloe Feoranzo, Eric",
    city: "Bangalore, India",
    cityId: 1,
    date: ["October 2020", "September 2020"],
    genre: "Nu Jazz",
  },
  {
    artistId: [2, 5],
    artistName: "Eric",
    city: "Bangalore, India",
    cityId: 1,
    date: ["August 2020", "January 2020"],
    genre: "Nu Jazz",
  }
];

const finalArr = [];
arr.forEach(o => {
  const tempArr = [];
  o.date.forEach(d => {
    o.date = d;
    tempArr.push(o);
  });
  finalArr.push(...tempArr)
});
console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: Should newArr be tempArr?

Comment: @BenStephens yes you're right, I didn't rename that one. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't quite work - the output has the same dates for each of the objects that get split. o.date = d; is probably the offender.

Comment: @BenStephens, could you please explain how its the same date? Because I just tried it and it works perfectly as the required output.

Comment: When I run it in the browser console I get "September 2020" for the 0th and 1st item and "January 2020" for the 2nd and 3rd item

Comment: The date value is getting duplicated.

Comment: I made a snippet of this with the original sample data to show what was being commented on - getting only the last in each of the date array.